# MS Excel: number permutations

Tags: excel

I need to generate all possible combination of a set of numbers,
I know it could be possible to generate this using any programing language.
I was wondering in case it is possible to have a formula in MS Excel?

eg. for a 3 digit number 123

```
ColA:ColB
1   : 123 
2   : 132 
3   : 213 
4   : 231 
5   : 312 
6   : 321
```

The solution should be scaleable as I am expecting to use it for a 9-digit number.

regards

Comment: Excel is in some sense a functional language, there are no side effects and only the current cell is updated. The number of possible combinations of a 9 digit number (duplicates ignored) is 9!=362880. Assuming you could write a formula that could pick the n:th permutation (you could use row() to determine which one), all you have to do is paste that formula in 362779 cell's ;-)

Comment: Further to @Lennart's comment: There are many formulas to enumerate permutations. Any Google search of GPU implementations of the Travelling Salesman problem should turn one up quickly.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Can you please post at least one link to such an Google search result? Maybe https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/combinatorics-using-excel-formulas-and-examples#TOC-Formula-using-help-column- could help. But this can't be found using keywords "Traveling Salesman problem".

Comment: @AxelRichter: The final method on this page, *PathFromRoutePermutation*, is such a calculation: http://cudafytuningtutorial.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CudafyTsp/GpuTsp4C.cs. For GPU implementations the *thread* info can be ignored, and *path* allowed to become a 1D array instead of 2D.

Answer (score 0):

You could just count the numbers (111111111_111111112...), put that all down a column, then for each row, use the middle() function to grab a char and convert it to text, one column for each digit.  Or do some division and modulos to grab each digit.  There's lots of ways.

If you don't get an answer, I can write a formula out in the morning. :)

Are duplicates allowed, like 111?  Or are they all unique digits?

Comment: Curious how you will "put all down a column" the numbers 111111111, 111111112, ..., 999999999 in Excel ;-).

Comment: In box a1 type "11111111" and "11111112" in a2.  Then either select the range (a1:a30) and hit ctrl-d.  OR double click in the bottom right corner of a1 and it should autofill that formula.OR you can click and drag the bottom right corner and it does the same thing

Comment: I'm a fan of the `Ctrl-d` option myself.

Comment: Thank you, I know this. But there are only 2^20 rows downwards in a Excel sheet. So starting with 11111111, 11111112, you will end with 12159686, not with 99999999. And this are only 8 digits.

Comment: I'd go to new columns personally (and then new sheets for each digit...  Is there a reason you need to use excel?  If so, do you need them to all be present at the same time?  Could you analyze it one at a time in one way or another?

Comment: Column a goes from 100xxxxxx through 120xxxxxx then b goes 120-140, c 140-160, etc... Would that be OK?  Or is there another way possible instead?  What's the whole application? May I ask?

Answer (score 0):

In opposite to some comments here I hadn't found an Excel solution for this. So here is my approach:

[image]

Formulas:

in `K1`: `=COUNTA(A1:I1)`

in `A2`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$J$362881,ROW()+$L2,COLUMN()+IF($K2+COLUMN()=$K$1+$K2,-$K2,IF($K2+COLUMN()>=$K$1,1,0)))
```

This formula copied to right til `I2`.

in `K2`:

```
=IF(ROW()<=FACT($K$1),$K$1+1-MATCH(0,MOD(ROW()-1,FACT($K$1+1-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})),-1),#N/A)
```

in `L2`: `=-FACT(K2)`

Row 2 can completely be copied downwards as needed.

Now in `A1:I1` we can input up to 9 values, from which the permutations shall be calculated.

This is derived from: http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=325